# Why is PHP outputting decimals with a -E

Tags: php

I am trying to round a decimal after a subtraction:

```
$decimal = round(0.000300-0.000200,6);
```

The out put I want is : 0.0001

but why is -1.0E-4 appearing? I know what it means, but why is it displaying this way? Is this some kind of php setting causing this?

Comment: php will try to present floats in a "minimal" format. if you want the full-blown decimals, then try `sprintf('%0.5f', $val)` to force 5 decimal places.

Comment: How are you outputting it?

Comment: @Adrian: I guess `echo sprintf('%0.5f', $val);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is rounding! Not giving format to display that number. If you want to display a float number with 6 digits after the point you should use PHP's number_format:

```
$decimal = round(0.000300-0.000200,6);

number_format($decimal,6);
```

Comment: I want it to round as well

Comment: Like a just did on my answer, @deArtish.